# Were the Challengers of the Unknown inspired by Doc Savage and his Fabulous Five?

Tags: inspiration, super-hero, jack-kirby

[The Challengers of the Unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challengers_of_the_Unknown) are often said to have been inspired by Doc Savage and his Fabulous Five, but I don’t know whether it's true or just fan speculation. Did Jack Kirby ever say whether the Challengers of the Unknown were inspired by Doc Savage and his Fabulous Five?

Comment: Said by whom?  Where?

Comment: Please read the question

Comment: The question just says "are often said to have been inspired."  It does _not_ say by whom.  It does _not_ say where or when; it doesn't quantify "often."  It sounds like an "everybody knows" fallacy to dress up a personal theory or headcanon.

Comment: Fwiw, this question was also asked on Quora: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-the-Challengers-of-the-Unknown-were-inspired-by-Doc-Savage-and-his-fabulous-five-Was-it-confirmed-in-Jack-Kirby-s-own-words-If-not-what-inspired-their-creation